# PHP Session errors

Tags: php

i have `session_start();` on line 2 of my home.php file and im getting this error:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/tmp/sess_6738dae837e7ca71b6daf43b6c11e158, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/integra/public_html/home.php on line 2

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/integra/public_html/home.php:2) in /home/integra/public_html/home.php on line 2
```

What do these usually mean? My hosting company have told me its nothing to do with them but im not so sure

Comment: Check your session save path in php.ini and change it if necessary   or         PHP does not have permissions to write on /tmp directory. You need to use chmod command to open /tmp permissions.

Comment: just set permissions to your /tmp/ that's all

Comment: its seems that your script doesn't have permissions to write on tmp folder, when you use session it creates file on your server.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the user that PHP is running as does not have write permissions to the `/tmp` directory, where session data is stored in the form of files.

Either your host has messed something up or you need to configure PHP to use another directory for session storage (your host will tell you what that might be, and you will need to call [`session_save_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) before starting the session).

Comment: Ok excellent - thank you i will check again with host